# Implementations with price restriction

Tags: wavesplatform

I have one question about asset script:
 It is possible to create token with script which allow to trade on WavesDex only for 1 usd? If sombody want to trade minimum or maximum of > 1< usd script will block this operation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. 
You should get something like this:

```
let tokenId = base58'token id here'
match tx {
  case ex : ExchangeTransaction =>
    let selectedToken = ex.sellOrder.assetPair.priceAsset == tokenId || ex.sellOrder.assetPair.amountAsset == tokenId
    let selectedPrice = ex.price == your_price_here
    selectedToken && selectedPrice
  case _ => true
}
```